# Form closing - MessageBoxButtons "Cancel" close the application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code line:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Message?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
    }
}
```

The point is: when the user click "Ok", the app is closing. If the user click on "Cancel" the result is the same: the app is closing and I don't want that. Could anyone understand what am I missing?

Comment: where do you have your code for the closing? this is just showing us that you know how to put code behind the ok button

Comment: Is on the main form, at the "Events" tab

Answer (score 4):

cancel closing via `FormClosingEventArgs` property `Cancel`

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{ 
   if (MessageBox.Show("Message?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) != DialogResult.OK)
       e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the Form to close in this event-handler, you need to set the FormClosingEventArgs. Simply set `e.Cancel = true;` in the case you don't want the form to be closed, e.g. in your if-block.